# Silencing ChromeDriver.exe logging

Tags: webdriver, watir, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running ruby unit tests against Chrome using watir-webdriver. Whenever a test is run and chromedriver.exe is launched output similar to below appears:

```
Started ChromeDriver
port=9515
version=26.0.1383.0
log=C:\Home\Server\Test\Watir\web\chromedriver.log
[5468:8796:0404/150755:ERROR:accelerated_surface_win.cc(208)] Reseting D3D device
[5468:8996:0404/150758:ERROR:textfield.h(156)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[WARNING:..\..\..\..\flash\platform\pepper\pep_module.cpp(63)] SANDBOXED
```

None of this impacts the correct functioning of the tests, but as one might imagine the appearance of "ERROR" and "WARNING" might be rather confusing to, for example, parsing rules in Jenkins looking for failures. Sure I can get really fancy with regular expression in the parsing rules, but it would be really nice to turn off this verbose and unnecessary logging on the part of chromedriver.exe. I have seen many mentions of this searching for an answer. No one has come up with a solution. Yes, chromedriver possibly has a "--silent" option, but there seems to be no way to pass that to the executable. Code similar to below is supposed to work, but has zero effect as far as I can see. Any ideas?

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
profile['--cant-make-any-switches-work-here-how-about-you'] = true
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :profile => profile, :switches => %w[--ignore-certificate-errors --disable-extensions --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate--allow-file-access]
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, the switch is -silent and it works from cmd. However I'm not sure how you can pass this to your script..

Answer (score 2):

Here's help for anyone else searching

Find ...`selenium\webdriver\chrome\service.rb`
Path start may differ on your system

And I added "-silent" to the passed parameters .... However, this silenced everything but the error/warning messages.

```
    def initialize(executable_path, port)
      @uri           = URI.parse "http://#{Platform.localhost}:#{port}"
      server_command = [executable_path, " -silent", "--port=#{port}"]

      @process       = ChildProcess.build(*server_command)
      @socket_poller = SocketPoller.new Platform.localhost, port, START_TIMEOUT

      @process.io.inherit! if $DEBUG == true
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

set `chromeOptions` with `key --log-level=3` this should shut it up

Answer (score 1):

I was able to divert the hundreds, yes hundreds, of chrome driver log messages that were showing up in cucumber stdout by using the :service_log_path argument.

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :service_log_path => 'chromedriver.out'
```

the `'-silent'`, or `'--silent'`, or ' `-silent'`, or `' --silent'` parameter suggested above did nothing when I added it to `...selenium\webdriver\chrome\service.rb`.  And having to tweak the gem itself is not a particularly viable solution.

I couldn't find a place to capture the chromedriver stderr and divert it to null (not to mention having to handle doing that in windows and in *nix/osx)

The driver should default to something way less verbose.  In this case INFO is way too verbose as hundreds of log entries pop out as INFO, 90%+ of them identical.

At least the :`service_log_path` argument works most of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `-Dwebdriver.chrome.logfile="/dev/null"` and/or `-Dwebdriver.chrome.args="--disable-logging"` to the options of java that runs `selenium-server-standalone-what.ever.jar`