# selenium chrome browser logging in console

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, web-crawler

I have been facing a problem with my python crawling project. I am using chrome with selenium in python for crawling and the environment is Windows 7. This is a console application. The problem is while the program is running for sometimes the console continuously outputs the following data about chrome browser:

```
**[044:202] AUTHORIZED; socket handshake complete
[044:211] F->C: ["fs",{"pr":"a"}]
[044:233] F->C: ["mf","mf4.0","4.0.1.13525",2,{"audioCodecs":[[103,"ISAC",1,0,16
000],[104,"ISAC",1,0,32000],[9,"G722",1,64000,16000],[102,"ILBC",1,13300,8000],[
0,"PCMU",1,64000,8000],[8,"PCMA",1,64000,8000],[107,"CN",1,0,48000],[106,"CN",1,
0,32000],[105,"CN",1,0,16000],[13,"CN",1,0,8000],[127,"red",1,0,8000],[126,"tele
phone-event",1,0,8000]],"audioRtpHdrExts":[{"id":1,"uri":"urn:ietf:params:rtp-hd
rext:ssrc-audio-level"}],"camDeviceName":"FH13FF-238","caps":15,"cpuArchitecture
":0,"cpuCacheSize":3145728,"cpuFamily":6,"cpuFlags":["sse2","ssse3","sse4_1","ss
e4_2"],"cpuHasSSE2":true,"cpuModel":37,"cpuSpeed":2527,"cpuStepping":5,"cpuVendo
r":"GenuineIntel","cpus":4,"cpusPhysical":2,"cryptoSuites":["AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA
1_80","AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_32"],"dataChannelVersion":1,"effectsVersion":10,"mac
hineModel":"Not available","remotingAssistanceAllowed":0,"remotingVersion":1,"re
nderer":2,"rtcpMux":true,"screencast":2,"screencastLocalPreview":1,"supportsConc
urrentSessions":true,"transports":["i","gice"],"videoCodecs":[[99,"H264-SVC",640
,360,30],[97,"H264",640,360,30],[98,"H263",640,360,30]],"videoRtpHdrExts":[{"id"
:2,"uri":"urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset"}]}]
[047:353] ClientChannel::HandleOnlineCheck: Starting check
[047:353] ClientChannel::HandleOnlineCheck: OK; current state: 3
[049:207] ClientChannel::HandleOnlineCheck: Starting check
[049:207] ClientChannel::HandleOnlineCheck: OK; current state: 3
[067:794] Starting client channel.
[067:796] Read port file, port=1836
[067:800] Initiated connection to GoogleTalkPlugin
[067:818] Socket connection established
[067:819] ClientChannel::ScheduleOnlineCheck: Online check in 5000ms
[067:820] Got cookie response, socket is authorized
[067:822] AUTHORIZED; socket handshake complete
[067:822] F->C: ["fs",{"pr":"a"}]
[067:836] F->C: ["mf","mf4.0","4.0.1.13525",2,{"audioCodecs":[[103,"ISAC",1,0,16
000],[111,"opus",2,64000,48000],[104,"ISAC",1,0,32000],[109,"CELT",1,64000,32000
],[110,"CELT",2,64000,32000],[9,"G722",1,64000,16000],[102,"ILBC",1,13300,8000],
[0,"PCMU",1,64000,8000],[8,"PCMA",1,64000,8000],[107,"CN",1,0,48000],[106,"CN",1
,0,32000],[105,"CN",1,0,16000],[13,"CN",1,0,8000],[127,"red",1,0,8000],[126,"tel
ephone-event",1,0,8000]],"audioRtpHdrExts":[{"id":1,"uri":"urn:ietf:params:rtp-h
drext:ssrc-audio-level"}],"camDeviceName":"FH13FF-238","caps":15,"cpuArchitectur
e":0,"cpuCacheSize":3145728,"cpuFamily":6,"cpuFlags":["sse2","ssse3","sse4_1","s
se4_2"],"cpuHasSSE2":true,"cpuModel":37,"cpuSpeed":2527,"cpuStepping":5,"cpuVend
or":"GenuineIntel","cpus":4,"cpusPhysical":2,"cryptoSuites":["AES_CM_128_HMAC_SH
A1_80","AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_32"],"dataChannelVersion":1,"effectsVersion":10,"ma
chineModel":"Not available","remotingAssistanceAllowed":1,"remotingVersion":1,"r
enderer":2,"rtcpMux":true,"screencast":2,"screencastLocalPreview":1,"supportsCon
currentSessions":true,"transports":["i","gice"],"videoCodecs":[[100,"VP8",640,40
0,30],[116,"red",640,400,30],[117,"ulpfec",640,400,30],[99,"H264-SVC",640,360,30
],[97,"H264",640,360,30],[98,"H263",640,360,30]],"videoRtpHdrExts":[{"id":2,"uri
":"urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset"}],"vsVersion":1}]
[067:850] F->C: ["getdevicestate","15","0",["__default_device","Microphone (Real
tek High Definition Audio)"],"0",["__default_device","Speakers (Realtek High Def
inition Audio)"],"0",["FH13FF-238","CyberLink Web Camera Filter"]]**  !
```

Please help me to get rid of this problem. I need to off such output from program.

Thanks,
Sohel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used selenium with python but this ruby example might be of some use: [Silencing ChromeDriver.exe logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822803/silencing-chromedriver-exe-logging)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but where to find the ".selenium\webdriver\chrome\service.rb"? And how to set the -silen params and where to set i can't understand. Could you please help me to find the path and where to add the option?

Comment: I am not very familiar with python but find the directory on your machine where pip installs packages. After finding that directory follow selenium-webdriver/lib/selenium/webdriver/chrome/support.py . In my case I was able to just search for the "webdriver" directory and find the ruby equivalent on my machine is ~5 minutes.